# why writeMetadataFileAndCommit in spark use synchronized block?

Tags: apache-spark

The `IndexShuffleBlockResolver::writeMetadataFileAndCommit` method will use synchronized block to write and rename the metadata file. But I think given a (shuffleID, mapID), there should be only one thread calling this method at the same time, so is this synchronized still needed? Here is the [link](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/a84e2b1eee3bb868f140bffeba4e19b1a56fa3fb/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/shuffle/IndexShuffleBlockResolver.scala#L362C26-L362C26) to code.